# Is it possible to restore Google Cloud Bigtable Table backup to a BigTable instance in another Google Cloud Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I want to restore a backed up Table from production BigTable instance in GCP Project A to non production BigTable instance in GCP Project B.
What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Have you looked [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/import-export)?

Comment: Yes. Here. https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/backups#limitations
And here. https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/managing-backups#restoring-backup

Comment: Backups exist to [save data from being lost by errors or corruption](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/backups#what-for) so in this case, backups is not really meant for this use case. This being said, did some research and found [something that might be useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398779/11987654).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bigtable recently launched cross-project backup restore; this will allow you to restore from a production Bigtable instance backup (in GCP Project A) to a different project (non-production Bigtable instance).

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/release-notes#December_08_2022